# Wordpress google compute engine - Error establishing a database connection

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine

Wordpress will be running like a charm and once every month, my site will crash with the error - "Error establishing a database connection". All I do is reset my VM instance on google compute engine and the site will be up again. However, this issue is occurring everyday now and is getting out of control. Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about compute engine and is not programing related.